# Unique row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to display a unique row from a SQL Server database. I have two tables called `UploadedData` and `DummyReportDetail`. I want to join those tables but I'm not getting a unique row using distinct.

This is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    D.TokenNo, D.UploadDate AS "Date", D.[Time], 
    D.SMSContent AS [Message], D.SMSType AS [SMS Type], 
    (SELECT COUNT(d.MobNo) FROM dbo.DummyReportDetail AS d 
     WHERE d.UploadDate = '31/12/2012' AND d.UserID = '2' 
       AND d.UserType = 'Reseller' AND d.TokenNo = U.TokenNo) AS "Count",
    D.DStatus AS "Status" 
FROM    
    dbo.DummyReportDetail AS D 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.UploadedData AS U ON D.TokenNo = U.TokenNo 
WHERE 
    D.UploadDate = '31/12/2012' AND D.UserID = '2' 
    AND D.UserType = 'Reseller' AND D.TokenNo = U.TokenNo  
ORDER BY 
    D.TokenNo DESC
```

My output for this query is:

```
Token-4 31/12/2012   11:23:59 AM   संपादकीय Unicode  2  SUBMITED
Token-4 31/12/2012   11:24:9 AM    संपादकीय Unicode  2  SUBMITED
Token-3 31/12/2012   10:21:31 AM   TestSMS Normal  1 SUBMITED
```

But I want this output:

```
Token-4 31/12/2012  11:24:9 AM  संपादकीय    Unicode  2  SUBMITED
Token-3 31/12/2012 10:21:31 AM  TestSMS    Normal   1  SUBMITED
```

Please Help Me...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Those three rows you get in the output are **not** duplicates - they differ on various columns - that's why `DISTINCT` won't get rid of them...

Answer (score 1):

```
 select distinct D.TokenNo, D.UploadDate as "Date",D.[Time], D.SMSContent as "Message",D.SMSType as "SMS Type", 
        (select count (d.MobNo) from dbo.DummyReportDetail as d 
           where d.UploadDate='31/12/2012' and d.UserID='2' 
           and d.UserType='Reseller' and d.TokenNo=U.TokenNo) as "Count"
          ,D.DStatus as "Status"
    from dbo.DummyReportDetail as D join dbo.UploadedData as U
    on D.TokenNo=U.TokenNo 
    where D.UploadDate='31/12/2012' and D.UserID='2' 
    and D.UserType='Reseller' and D.TokenNo=U.TokenNo  group by D.tokenNo  order by D.TokenNo desc
```

Add group by TokenNo

Answer (score 0):

You will need to apply grouping in order to achieve what you need.
In this case, you need to group on every single column, and get the maximum date:

```
select D.TokenNo, D.[Time], D.SMSContent as "Message",D.SMSType as "SMS Type", 
(select count (d.MobNo) from dbo.DummyReportDetail as d 
   where d.UploadDate='31/12/2012' and d.UserID='2' 
   and d.UserType='Reseller' and d.TokenNo=U.TokenNo) as "Count"
  ,D.DStatus as "Status", MAX(D.UploadDate) as "Date"
from dbo.DummyReportDetail as D join dbo.UploadedData as U
on D.TokenNo=U.TokenNo 
where D.UploadDate='31/12/2012' and D.UserID='2'
group by D.TokenNo, D.[Time], D.SMSContent, D.SMSType, Count, D.DStatus
and D.UserType='Reseller' and D.TokenNo=U.TokenNo  order by D.TokenNo desc
```

You may additionally also want to consider rewriting your query to use grouping to replace your current inner query for the "Count" field. Joining the table will be more efficient than your current query, as a join is performed once, while now your subquery is run once for each row you get in your resultset.